# Reference for $a^n+b^n+c^n$ has bounded distinct prime factors iff $a=b=c$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

**Theorem:** Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers for which $a^n+b^n+c^n$ has at most $k$ distinct prime divisors for all integers $n\ge 1$, for some fixed constant $k$. Then $a=b=c$.

---

I read from an [old thread on AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h4513s1_finite_p_divisors) that this result is due to a certain Reutter. I tried to search his name, but I really didn't find anything..

Can you find a refence for the above result?

Comment: That AoPS page you linked to is unreadable. Is its content relevant?

Comment: I suppose "has always" means "for all natural number $n$".

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not really.. There is just an elementary proof which you can skip

Comment: @ÉricGuirbal For sure, I will edit it with your suggestion ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

likely this Otmar Reutter, probably no Ph.D., who is quoted in a 1963 issue of [Elemente der Mathematik](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/voltoc?pid=elemat-001:1963:18), volume 18, pageS 89-90. Found in [SIERPINSKI](http://www.isinj.com/usamo/250%20Problems%20in%20Elementary%20Number%20Theory%20-%20Sierpinski%20%281970%29.pdf) 
pages 27-28, 123 at reference 17. At the time, O. Reutter lived in Ochsenhausen, Germany. Maybe the Swiss digital library gives a way to search Elemente for all contributions (including this challenge answer) by him. Or her.

Hmmm. Maybe not. But, maybe once a year, the M.A.A. Monthly lists all the people who answered something in the "Problems and Solutions" column that year. Elemente might do something similar.

[image]

Comment: I don't think something similar to Knuth's lemma (or Zsigmondy theorem's) holds for more than two variables, don't you?

Anyway, I found that name on the book of Sierpisky, but I wasn't sure it was the same person..

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti, I think it is the same person. I do not see anything completely automated, but it allows me to click on each issue in each volume (year) of the Elemente, in particular to click on Aufgaben. At that time, O. Reutter was regularly answering questions. He also posted some questions. If really important, i would examine all the Aufgaben columns, gradually widening either side of 1963. Maybe, maybe, he also wrote articles. Might be some way to write to Elemente and get a quicker answer, yes or no.

Comment: Thanks for the update, and for the name :) I will follow your advices.. Ps. Do you know anything about your last question?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti, not really. I did think it made more sense to ask about the radicals than talk about the gcds, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer    Let me think, there is a good chance your question was a challenge in the same magazine by Sierpinski, he and Erdos were regular contributors. When Reutter asked questions, they were more about $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Thank you Will :) Meanwhile, I checked all "Aufgaben" from 1951 to 1980 made by O. Reutter, they were doing something in the same spirit of Mathematical Reflection nowadays (but no, I didn't find anything on the problem)

Comment: For your last question, if I am not wrong you can prove a lower bound for rad(a^n+b^n+c^n) which holds for infinitely many n; but what do you mean exactly with comparison?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti, I had not thought it through, I figured one way to get no upper bound on the number of distinct prime factors would be if each one of the $m,n$ expressions has a prime factor the other lacks. This would be milder than demanding gcd = 1, but still pretty strong. Anyway, it is a pity AOPS. as well as this site, do not do better with references. A theorem used by all high school children in one country may be completely unknown in another. Same with contest preparation books, they name results in one book, but non-readers won't recognize the name.

Comment: Indeed, that's what happened at 2012RMO with Kobayashi theorem, which is very interesting in my opinion (see http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h362152s1_kobayashis_theorem ). About the radicals problem, are you saying that if $\text{rad}(m) \neq \text{rad}(n)$, then there is no upper bound on what..?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti, I know very little about this, it was just a thought. I did look at AOPS again, the entry that mentions Reutter could be referring to just two numbers, $a^n + b^n:$ "Plz explain me, cause really this problem take me so long time though the case of two numbers is easy to see! (This is called Reutter theorem)" Also, although hard to read at present, it seems possible that the AOPS post contains a correct proof. Worth checking what it really does say, at any rate.

Comment: Wah.. I didn't think before he could be referring to the case of two variables O.o However, the case $a^n \pm b^n$ is well-known (I don't know the name, but you can use, for instance, Zsigmondy theorem, which I feel it is an overkill, as it proves the existence of a primitive divisor for almost each n..)

Answer (score 1):

from AOPS in 2004.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

A. March 6, 2004: Let $a,b,c$ be natural numbers (nonzero), such that $a^n + b^n + c^n$ has finite prime divisors, $n=1,2,\ldots$

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

G. March 13, 2004, 1:35 PM: Let's assume they aren't equal. Then let $d = \gcd(a,b,c).$ we can obviously work with $a'=a/d,$  $b'=b/d,$  $c'=c/d,$ which are not all equal to $1,$ and  $\gcd(a',b',c')=1.$ Let me call $a'=a, b'=b, c'=c$ (for simplicity).

Let $p_i$ be the primes which are the divisors of $$S_n = a^n + b^n + c^n,$$ with $i$ from $1$ to $k.$ Let
$$ n_0 = 2 \Pi (p_i - 1).  $$
If one of the numbers $a,b,c$ is divisible by $p_i,$ then $$S_{n_0} \equiv 2 \pmod {p_i},$$
and if none of the numbers $a,b,c$ is divisible by $p_i,$ then $$S_{n_0} \equiv 3 \pmod {p_i}.$$
This means that $S_{k n_0}$ is of the form $2^x 3^y$ for all $k \in \mathbf N.$ It's easy to see that it's $2 \pmod 4$ because of the $2$ in front of the product, so it has either the form $2 \cdot 3^x$ or $3^x.$

***I'll finish it a bit later, cause my mom wants some time on the computer, so she's rushing me.***

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

G. March 13, 2004, 6:54 PM: I'll pick up from where I left:

Let $$ A  = a^{n_0}. $$ In the same way we get $B$ and $C$ from $b$ and $c$ respectively. We have 
$$  A^k + B^k + C^k =$$ a power of $3$ for all $k$ or $2 \cdot$ a power of $3$ for all $k.$ Let's assume it's the first one (the second is basically the same).

At the same time, we have $\gcd(A,B,C) = 1.$ This means that at least 2 of $A,B,C$ are coprime with $$ A^t + B^t + C^t, $$ with $t$ chosen such that the sum is greater than $3$ ( such a $t$ exists, because we assume $A,$ $B,$ or $C > 1$), so let's assume those two are $A$ and $B.$ Take $k$ to be
$$ k = \phi(A^t + B^t + C^t).  $$
If $3|C$ we get 
$$  A^k + B^k + C^k \equiv 2 \pmod {3^{\mbox{something}}}  $$
which is false, and if $3$ does not divide $C,$ we get 
$$  A^k + B^k + C^k \equiv 3 \pmod {3^{\mbox{something} > 1}}  $$
so we have a contradiction again.

I think this ends it.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

P.  March 13, 2004, 11:41 PM: Dear G, sorry, maybe I am stupid, but I do not see why $k n_0$ has the form $2^x 3^y.$ Please explain me, cause really this problem take me so long time though the case of two numbers is easy to see! (This is called Reutter theorem)

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

G. March 13, 2004, 11:54 PM: If, for example, $a$ is divisible by $p_i,$ then $b$ and $c$ aren't (we assume $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$), so 
$$  b^{k n_0} \equiv  c^{k n_0}  \equiv 1 \pmod {p_i} $$ and $a \equiv 0 \pmod {p_i},$ so
$$  S_{k n_0} \equiv 2 \pmod {p_i} $$

If, on the other hand, none of $a,b,c$ are divisible by $p_i$ (this is for a certain $i$ from $1$ to $k$), then 
$$  a^{k n_0} \equiv  b^{k n_0} \equiv  c^{k n_0}  \equiv 1 \pmod {p_i}, $$ so
$$  S_{k n_0} \equiv 3 \pmod {p_i} $$

This means that the remainder of $  S_{k n_0}  \pmod {p_i} $ is either $2$ or $3,$ for all $i$ from $1$ to $k.$ If there is a prime divisor 
of $  S_{k n_0}$ other than $2$ or $3,$ then it can't be among $p_i$ with  $i$ from $1$ to $k,$ so the prime divisors of   $  S_{k n_0}$ aren't contained in the finite set (this was the initial assumption: that all $S_t$ have their prime divisors in the finite set 
$$  \{ p_i | 1 \leq i \leq k  \}.    $$ This shows that the form of $  S_{k n_0}$ is $2^x 3^y.$

Hope it's all correct and clear.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

P.  March 15, 2004, 4:26 AM: Well done, G, I think it's correct!

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: Do you want to finish later too? :P

Comment: @Paolo, I'm getting there. I'm typesetting it on my home computer, that is much nicer than typesetting on this site, then I just paste a correct section of Latex here. Note that I made a guess about the definition of $S_n.$ Also, the condition $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$ actually allows for some prime $p_i$ to divide two out of three of $(a,b,c),$ as along as it does not also divide the third. That may or may not matter.

Comment: Suppose that $p_i$ divides two or them. $p_i$ by definition has to be a divisor of $a^k-b^k+c^k$, for some $k>0$; but it would imply that it divides also the third one, contradicting that $\text{gcd}(a,b,c)=1$ ;)

Comment: Alright, the main thing is for you to go through every line. What do you think of my definition for $S_n?$ At AOPS there was only the letter $a$ and a surprising summation symbol.

Comment: It's correct, anyway it was just written $S_n=\sum a^n$ :) The solution seem to work to me, don't you? [I had no doubt in truth, grobber is really smart]

Comment: Ahhh, glad you like the $S_n,$ it made the most sense to me. Correctness, i have no idea, i will finish typing it here, then later print out and read. I don't much like reading on the computer screen, I prefer paper where i can adjust the distance to my eyes, matter of poor near vision. Still Spain 1, Ukraine 0.

Comment: There's no hurry :) [ot] I don't follow soccer, but I am glad for Spain, it's a place where I'd really  like to live for next years [/ot]

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti, repetition of the symbol $k,$ in $k = \phi(A^t + B^t + C^t)$ it should be some other letter, maybe $s,$ same in the next two displayed  items with $A^k + B^k + C^k$

Comment: I see, he actually uses $k$ for several different things. I will try to sort that out later. Given your reactions so far, it probably does not change anything very much.

Comment: If you change those three $k$ in $s$, as you correctly pointed out, the proof would be cleaner..

Comment: Right now I am looking at the earlier introduction of $S_{k n_0};$ since he says it is for all $k \in \mathbb N,$ I think this ought to be yet another letter.

Comment: He just uses $k$ "locally", up to the second half of his second, and that moment he fixes it equal to $\phi(A^t+B^t+C^t)$ up to the end.. Anyway, I have to I agree that the notation is not really clear

Comment: Please do me a favor and write a real proof of the thing, more or less along these lines, but with some care about the order of statements, what are the assumptions and where d they apply; then post as an answer to this question, I guess tomorrow. For the moment, i just cannot follow this.

Comment: While trying to rewrite it, I realized grobber proved something weaker than what has been asked in the problem. My fault that I didn't realized it before. Specifically, he proves that the set of prime divisors of $\{a^n+b^n+c^n: n\ge 1\}$ is finite if and only if $a=b=c$. Well...

Comment: Excellent. I will be away for a few hours, I am interested to see how it turns out. I would think it is late in Italy, evidently you are young and full of energy. Note that the original question on AOPS was not very clear either.

Comment: Not so much energy in truth :P Anyway, you are correct also about your last point, maybe it was what the OP was really asking there: in any case, I hope this is more readable now.. [So far, we don't have a complete solution eh?]

Answer (score 1):

[Just an attempt to rewrite the above proof, due to grobber]

**(Weaker) Claim:** Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers. Then the set of prime divisors of $\{a^n+b^n+c^n: n\ge 1\}$ is finite if and only if $a=b=c$.

*Proof:* The if part is trivial. For the converse, let us suppose without loss of generality that $\text{gcd}(a,b,c)=1$ (in particular, at least one is greater than $1$), define the sequence $(S_n)_{n\ge 1}$ by $S_n:=a^n+b^n+c^n$, and assume by contradition that the set $P$ of primes dividing at least one $S_n$ is finite.

Define $n_0=2\prod_{p \in P}{(p_i-1)}$. Then the factorization of $S_{n_0}$ will have by hypothesis only primes in $P$. In particular, for each prime $p \in P$, at most one integer in $\{a,b,c\}$ can be multiple of $p$. It follows that, for each $p \in P$ and each $k\ge 1$, it holds $S_{kn_0}=a^{kn_0}+b^{kn_0}+c^{kn_0}$ has remainder $2$ or $3$ modulo $p$. But these remainders have to be $0$ modulo some $p \in P$, hence $S_{kn_0}$ will be of the type $2^x 3^y$ for some nonnegative integers $x,y$.

Notice that $n_0$ is even, therefore $S_{kn_0}$ cannot be multiple of $4$, since by assumption $a,b$ and $c$ cannot be all even. Moreover all $\{S_{kn_0}: k\ge 1\}$ have the same parity. Hence they will be all of the type $2\cdot 3^y$ or $3^y$, for some integers $y$. We solve the second case:

We must have $S_{kn_0}$ divides $S_{(k+1)n_0}$ whenever $k$ is sufficiently large. Notice that at least two between $a,b,c$ have to be coprime with $S_{tn_0}$, where $t$ is a sufficiently large fixed positive integer. By construction $S_{tn_0}$ is a power of $3$, let us say $3^q$, with $q\ge 2$. Then $S_{(t-1)n_0}$ has to divide $S_{tn_0}$, which is impossible modulo $9$.

Comment: You've done a fine job removing the repeated meaning of symbols...I'm stuck on the last paragraph; not sure why anything needs to be sufficiently large. However, my main complaint is that $2^2 + 2^2 + 1^2 = 9.$ Maybe it will make sense tomorrow. Also $5^2 + 1^2 + 1^2 = 27,$ $8^2 + 4^2 + 1^2 = 81.$

Comment: Oh we don't need the "sufficiently large" the first time. The second time is just to make sure that the sum is, let us say, greater than 9. About the possibility that some $S_n$ are multiple of 9, fine, but we want to find a contradiction claiming that it is not possible that they are all powers of 3, once we fix a,b, and c..