# Number of distinct prime factors of $a^n+b^n+c^n$

Tags: number-theory

This question is a generalization of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475267/reference-for-anbncn-has-bounded-distinct-prime-factors-iff-a-b-c) other one.

**Problem:** Given a constant $k$ and distinct positive integers $a,b,c$, prove that there exist an integer $n>1$ for which the number of distinct prime factors of $a^n+b^n+c^n$ is at least $k$.

Moreover, do you know if there exists some quantitative bound of this type with order, let's say, greater than $\ln\ln\ln n$? I mean, if $a^n+b^n+c^n$ would behave really randomly, then by the Erdos-Kac theorem $\omega(a^n+b^n+c^n)$ would have normal order $\ln \ln (a^n+b^n+c^n) \gg \ln n$..

Answer (score 0):

Let denote te phrase as $A=a^n+b^n+c^n$. It can be shown that if $a=x-y$, $b=y-z$ and $c=z-x$ then A can be factorized as follows:

If $n=6k-1$, then:

$(x-y)^n+(y-z)^n+(z-x)^n=n(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)$

If $n=6k+1$, then:

$(x-y)^n+(y-z)^n+(z-x)^n=n(x-y)(y-z)(z-x)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)^2$

Now following cases can be considered:

1- n is prime and a, b and c are co-primes; considering the fact that $x-y$ and other factors are even , then  A has at least two prime factors; i.e. $n$ and $2$.

2- If n is not prime ; $n=d^{\alpha}.e^{\beta}. . . $, then A has at least $t+1$ distinct primes, where t is number of primes in n.

3- if factors are also composite, in addition to being even, then number of distinct primes is greater than $t+1$, where t is number of primes in n.

Comment: Dear sirous, if you make the substitution $a=x-y$, $b=y-z$ and $c=z-x$, together with $a,b,c>0$, you would obtain $0<a+b+c=(x-y)+(y-z)+(z-x)=0$.. Also, are you sure about your identities?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti, I posted a question on this, you can see it in new questions. I would appreciate seeing your answer or comment on that. I proposed these identities by induction. there is probably stronger argument to verify or reject it.