# Olympiad problem: Prove that there are infinitely many primes which divide the sequence $\{ S(k) \} _{k\in \mathbb{N}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Question:**

> Let $a_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ be an Arithmetic Progression.
>
> Define $$S(k)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^k$$
>
> Prove that there are infinitely many primes which divide the sequence  $\{ S(k) \} _{k\in \mathbb{N}}$

**Doubt:**

What is the question trying to mean? I am not getting what they are asking to prove. Can someone explain that to me first? What do I have to prove? It's quite unclear to me.

**Edit 1:**
These are the solutions which my friend provided. I feel that the Part b (for the case $p>n$) is incorrect. Can you please check? He eventually claims that if $p>(n+1)^2$, then all such $p$ will divide $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^p \pmod p$ but that's not correct. It may hold for some terms and construction of such terms would solve the  problem but his claim is not true. Please check (the four snapshots below).

[image: P1]
[image: P2]
[image: P3]
[image: P4]

Comment: They are asking you to prove that the set $\{p\mid p$ is prime and $\exists k, p\mid S(k)\}$ is infinite.

Comment: The problem transcription is a bit unclear. Yet my best guess would be that you are to prove that the there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p\mid S(k_p)$ for some exponent $k_p$ (that may depend on $p$).

Comment: There is an answer already, so it is too late to delete.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yeah, anyone can proceed on deleting it. I'm just closing this down. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Has this been closed? I flagged to close it down. But if it has revived, please check Edit 1.

Comment: Please check **Edit 1** as posted above.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently, for every finite set of primes $P$ and for every fixed *distinct positive* integers $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, there exists $k \in \mathbf{N}$ such that
$$
p \,\,\text{ divides }\,\, a_1^k+\cdots+a_n^k
$$
for some $p \notin P$. This is solved in much greater generality [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08784) where, in particular, it is proved that
$$
\limsup_{k\to \infty}\,\#\{p: p \,\,\text{ divides }\,\, a_1^k+\cdots+a_n^k\}=\infty.
$$

Ps. Note that if you remove "distinct" then your claim is false, e.g., $2^k+2^k$.

Ps2. What is the source?

Comment: I got it as an Olympiad Problem from my friend.

Comment: @Mathbg I did know of some special cases in Math Olympiad problems, but not in this form. However, see the answer "Weaker claim" here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475267/reference-for-anbncn-has-bounded-distinct-prime-factors-iff-a-b-c